# Jquery autocomplete with codeigniter on large data (getting cities in country based on input)

Tags: jquery, performance, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am working on jquery autocomplete to populate cities (100k of cities in the world) in the world in codeigniter. Our developers did already but every key press calling controller function for cities. It is taking too much time to populate autocomplete to show. I will show code below

```
Jquery:
        $("#venuecity_country").autocomplete("<?php echo base_url(); ?>venue/get_city_country/",{ 
            //width: 480,
            matchContains: true,
            minChars: 1,
            onItemSelect:selectItem
        });

        function findValue(li) {
            console.log(li);
            var sValue = li.value;

            $('#event-search-results-content').ngsearch({location:true,locationValue:sValue});
        }

        function selectItem(li) {
            findValue(li);
            $("#city_country").val('');
        }

Controller:
        function get_city_country()
            {
                $query = $this->Venue_Model->get_city_county($this->session->userdata('venue_cntry'));
                if(!empty($query)) 
                {
                    foreach ($query as $row) {
                        echo $row['city'].','.$row['country_name']. "\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $get_country = $this->Venue_Model->getLocationInfoByIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                    $query = $this->Venue_Model->get_city_county($get_country);
                    if(!empty($query)) {
                        foreach ($query as $row) {
                            echo $row['city'].','.$row['country_name']. "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

Model:
         function get_city_county($session_country)
            {
                $this->db->select('world_cities.country,world_cities.city,world_countries.country_name,world_countries.country_code');
                $this->db->join('world_countries','world_countries.country_code = world_cities.country');
                $this->db->where('world_countries.country_name',$session_country);
                $this->db->or_where('world_countries.country_id',$session_country);
                $this->db->or_where('world_countries.country_code',$session_country);
                $query = $this->db->get('world_cities');
                if(!empty($query))
                {
                        return $query->result_array(); 
                }
            }
```

What is the fastest way to get all cities based on user input for autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

you can use limit in query and front side use infinite scrolling.so it will take less time compare to all city record

you Change in model :

```
function get_city_county($session_country)
        {
            $this->db->select('world_cities.country,world_cities.city,world_countries.country_name,world_countries.country_code');
            $this->db->join('world_countries','world_countries.country_code = world_cities.country');
            $this->db->where('world_countries.country_name',$session_country);
            $this->db->or_where('world_countries.country_id',$session_country);
            $this->db->or_where('world_countries.country_code',$session_country);
            $this->db->limit(10);
            $query = $this->db->get('world_cities');
            if(!empty($query))
            {
                    return $query->result_array(); 
            }
        }
```

change in Jquery:

```
$("#venuecity_country").autocomplete("<?php echo base_url(); ?>venue/get_city_country/",{ 
        //width: 480,
        matchContains: true,
        minChars: 1,
        onItemSelect:selectItem,
        open: function (event, ui) {
             $('<li class=""><a href="#" id="see_more" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span class="label">See More Result</span></a></li>').appendTo('ul.ui-autocomplete');
        }
    });

    function findValue(li) {
        console.log(li);
        var sValue = li.value;

        $('#event-search-results-content').ngsearch({location:true,locationValue:sValue});
    }

    function selectItem(li) {
        findValue(li);
        $("#city_country").val('');
    }
```

so it will return only top 10 record with See more record link.see more link redirect to new page and in this page load all record.

Comment: Sorry! Can u explain it briefly with example?